# Converting bash-like globs to SQL filters with Python

Tags: python, sql, bash, glob

I would like to convert bash-like globbing patterns to Python string comparisons. I am writing a command-line program which will called in the following way

```
myprog users list a*
```

The program would then internally use SQLAlchemy 1.1.3 to execute the following query:

```
self.session.query(User).filter(User.uid.like('a%'))
```

The idea is that bash-like globbing patterns would behave in a manner similar to what one would expect from a standard bash function.

I can obviously just parse the last argument myself, but I am not sure how elegantly I could do that and what corner-cases I might miss. So I was wondering:

Is there a Python package which can perform such conversion or does anyone have an idea how to implement such functionality in a compact way?

Comment: One thing to note is that a shell glob can be in the middle eg `foo*bar` but with some sql databases the wildcard must be at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Why not just `myprog users list a%` otherwise you need to escape the glob or the shell will get it first

Comment: @jordanm Yeah, I realise that a the mapping is going to have some limitations.  Having said that, ```uid LIKE "foo%bar"``` seems to work on MariaDB, which is what I am using.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano That's a good point.  I had forgotten about the shell having first dibs on the glob. Having to escape the glob would completely undermine the idea of converting simple glob on the command line. However, it looks like for a simple case I could still just use quoting, e.g. do ```myprog users list 'a*'``` and replace the ```*``` by a ```%```.